# casting mutable array is still considered non-mutable in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swift2, nsmutablearray

I tried casting AnyObject data to mutable array but it still worked like a non-mutable array and crashes on run-time after trying to mutate it. Can someone explain please?

Like I am getting some data from JSON and I know it is going to be of Array data type (I am naming it data), now I cast it to mutable array, suppose like this:

let mutArray: NSMutableArray = data as! NSMutableArray

but mutArray still remains as a non-mutable array when I later try to mutate it. This code worked perfect few months back and now it is giving issues like I am trying to mutate a non-mutable array.

Comment: Would you mind including some code that might make your steps a bit more clear?

Comment: @FishStix: Hello, I edited my question again. Hope I am able to explain it better now?!

Comment: Please show us how `data` is populated

Comment: @appzYourLife: I am getting it through JSON. So it is a dictionary, and using a key I get "data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because casting doesn't actually change an object in any way, it just tells the compiler it's of a certain type. In other words, it only affects the way the code is type-checked, it doesn't actually change the behavior of the code at runtime. To actually change an `NSArray` into an `NSMutableArray` you'd need to:

```
let mutArray = NSMutableArray(array: data)
```

This line actually creates a new `NSMutableArray` and populates it with your `data` array.

If your code worked before, then for some reason, your original data must have *already* been an `NSMutableArray`. It's actually pretty common for `NSArray`s to secretly be `NSMutableArray`s (though it is of course a bad idea to rely on that fact from any given method, since as we just learned, it could change at any moment).

Comment: Okay, but the same thing worked before but not now. Is it that memory structure of Swift is changing? I am just trying to understand this better, that's why so many questions.

Comment: @Max_Rai: Edited. Basically, you were lucky before.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time!